# how to create word documents from a large excel file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-word, oledb, mailmerge

I have a large excel file(227,000 records) and I'm trying to create a word document using a template for each row in the excel file. Usually the application that creates these word documents uses an excel file with only a couple thousand, but when trying to run the large file it just takes WAY TOO LONG! I was wondering if any one knew of a way to speed up the process.

**EDIT** 1/07/2014

Here is my revised code:

```
Using exConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(excelConnection)
            exConn.Open()
            Using countCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [payhst$]", exConn)
                totalCount = countCommand.ExecuteScalar
            End Using
        End Using
        If totalCount > 0 Then

            sectionCount = totalCount / 5000
            wrdApp.Visible = False
            wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(templateName)
            wrdApp.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft Office Live Meeting 2007 Document Writer"

            wrdApp.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.CreateHeaderSource(Name:="Header" + count.ToString + ".doc", HeaderRecord:="CLT,PREV LOAN,NCT,NEW LOAN,STREET," & _
                                                       "CITY,ST,ZIP,PAYHST JAN,PAYHST FEB," & _
                                                       "PAYHST MAR,PAYHST APR,PAYHST MAY,PAYHST JUN," & _
                                                       "PAYHST JUL,PAYHST AUG,PAYHST SEP,PAYHST OCT," & _
                                                       "PAYHST NOV,PAYHST DEC")
            For i = 1 To sectionCount
                wrdApp.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(Name:=fileName, SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `payhst$A" + countA.ToString + ":T" + countT.ToString + "`")
                saveDocName = WSHShell.specialFolders.item("Desktop") & "\HarpTestDocuments\HarpTif" & Today.Date.ToString("MMyyyy") + count.ToString + ".tif"
                wrdApp.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Destination = 0
                wrdApp.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Execute(Pause:=False)
                SplitAndSave(wrdApp.ActiveDocument)

                countA += 5000
                countT += 5000

                If countA > totalCount Then
                    countA = totalCount
                End If
                If countT > totalCount Then
                    countT = totalCount
                End If

            Next
            wrdDoc.Close(SaveChanges:=False)
            wrdApp.Quit(SaveChanges:=False)
            wrdApp = Nothing
            wrdDoc = Nothing

        End If
Private Sub SplitAndSave(ByRef doc As Word.Document)
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim newdoc As Document = New Document
        Dim saveNameCount As Integer = 1
        Dim sections As Integer = doc.Sections.Count

        For i = sections - 1 To 1 Step -1
            doc.Sections(i).Range.Copy()
            wrdApp.Documents.Add(templateName)
            wrdApp.ActiveDocument.Range.Paste()
            RemoveAllSectionBreaks(wrdApp.ActiveDocument)
            'newdoc = doc.Sections(i).Range
            saveDocName = WSHShell.specialFolders.item("Desktop") & "\HarpTestDocuments\HarpTif" & Today.Date.ToString("MMyyyy") + saveNameCount.ToString + ".tif"
            With wrdApp.ActiveDocument
                .PrintOut(OutputFileName:=saveDocName, PrintToFile:=True)
                .Close(SaveChanges:=False)
            End With
            saveNameCount += 1
        Next i

    End Sub
```

Well I got the time down to 5000 records is 30 min. I still think this is a long time.

**Does anyone know of a different way other than mail merge or form fields to create a word document from excel data?**

Comment: Do you think saving the Excel file as csv and then using the csv(text file) as data source for mailmerge would make a difference?

Comment: I suspect that the main problem is that you are outputting to a new document, which means that you are creating a document with 227,000 sections and pages. Even splitting the merge into 10 smaller chunks /might/ improve things. You /might/ be able to do that with a loop that constructs multiple SQL statements along the lines of "SELECT TOP 22700 * FROM ( SELECT TOP 200000 * FROM `payhst$` ORDER BY some_suitable_fields DESC ) ORDER BY some_suitable_fields ASC" (I would probably do smaller splits) but right now I cannot check whether TOP works with an Excel source.

Comment: I tested just to see if it would let me use TOP but the command failed.
`wrdApp.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(Name:=templateName, SQLStatement:="SELECT TOP 5000 * FROM ``payhst$``")`

Comment: Not sure the syntax ``payhst$`` will work. Not familiar with the "escaping" rules for VB.NET but I wpuld have thought `payhst$` would be enough. I tend to use the Jet syntax of [payhist$] for clarity and ""payhist$"" if I have to go for the less clear option. Other than that, the TOP clause seems to work OK here with a small, test Excel source.

Comment: I have tried doing [payhst$] but the command always failed. It worked when I put the tildy(`) around it.  Could you post the code that you used? When I tried I got the error "Command Failed".

Comment: Sorry for the delay - for some reason I lost track of this particular question. Doubtless you have found your way through somehow, but if not, the problem I saw was that you had two backquotes either side of the sheet name, when you only needed one. But backquotes seem to go missing via this editor and I hadn't noticed.